# TimeSpan.Parse time format hhmmss

Tags: c#, timespan

in c# i have time in format hhmmss like 124510 for 12:45:10 and i need to know the the TotalSeconds. i used the TimeSpan.Parse("12:45:10").ToTalSeconds but it does'nt take the format hhmmss. Any nice way to convert this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This might help

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("124510", "hhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            Console.WriteLine("Total Seconds: " + d.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Note this will not handle 24HR times, to parse times in 24HR format you should use the pattern **HHmmss**.

Comment: That 24HR Time comment probably just saved me about a day of banging my head on a wall. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Parse the string to a DateTime value, then subtract it's Date value to get the time as a TimeSpan:

```
DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact("124510", "HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan time = t - t.Date;
```

Comment: DateTime.TimeOfDay gives you a TimeSpan straight off.

Comment: You should use TimeOfDay instead of t - t.Date

Comment: Wow, thanks. I've been using the above method all over my code, and even had a `ToTime` extension method at one stage. Facepalm!

Answer (score 6):

You have to decide the receiving time format and convert it to any consistent format.

Then, you can use following code:

**Format: hh:mm:ss (12 Hours Format)**

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("10:45:10", "hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double totalSeconds = dt.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;    // Output: 38170.0
```

**Format: HH:mm:ss (24 Hours Format)**

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("22:45:10", "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double totalSeconds = dt.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;    // Output: 81910.0
```

In case of format mismatch, FormatException will be thrown with message: "**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**"

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the colons (or other separators), for what reason it can't handle them, I don't know. See [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) on MSDN, and the accepted answer, from Jon, to [Why does TimeSpan.ParseExact not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719055/why-does-timespan-parseexact-not-work).

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to work with also milliseconds like this format "01:02:10.055" then you may do as following;

```
public static double ParseTheTime(string givenTime)
{
var time = DateTime.ParseExact(givenTime, "hh:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
return time.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;
}
```

This code will give you corresponding seconds.
Note that you may increase the number of 'f's if you want to adjust precision points.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the string will always be hhmmss, you could do something like:

```
TimeSpan.Parse(
    timeString.SubString(0, 2) + ":" + 
    timeString.Substring(2, 2) + ":" + 
    timeString.Substring(4, 2)))
```

Comment: i cant garantee that the string will always be hhmmss. I need to put the format in a .settings file