# What is wrong with this TimeSpan.ParseExact line?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-4.0, datetime-format

I am receiving a FormatError exception from this call to TimeSpan.ParseExact, but the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) that I am reading says that this format should be correct:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact("172100", "HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Can someone please tell me why this is not working? I am doing almost exactly the same thing with a call to DateTime.ParseExact and this works fine:

```
DateTime datetTime = DateTime.ParseExact("090820", "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TimeSpan does not use the same formatting rules as DateTime.

You want hhmmss, not HHmmss.

You're looking at the wrong page in MSDN - you want something like:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx

Answer (score 5):

With ref to this more accurate documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx

You need to use `hh` for hours, not `HH`.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx), hours are represented by "h" rather than "H".

So this works fine:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact("172100", "hhmmss", 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The documentation you linked to is for custom *date and time* format strings, which aren't the same. They're for `DateTime.ParseExact` etc; the documentation I linked to is for `TimeSpan.ParseExact` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are try to use `DateTime` format strings to parse a `TimeSpan`. `TimeSpan` has its own (slightly different) format strings. See MSDN for a complete listing: [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx)

In particular, change `HH` to `hh`. This will give you:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact("172100",
                                        "hhmmss", // Note this parameter
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse the string to a DateTime value, then subtract it's Date value to get the time as a TimeSpan:

```
DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact("172100", "HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan time = t - t.Date;
```

Comment: There is no reason to get DateTime involved.

Comment: This is a reasonable workaround for code that needs to run on older versions of .NET.  TimeSpan.ParseExact() requires .NET 4.

Comment: An answer to [TimeSpan.Parse time format hhmmss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833830/timespan-parse-time-format-hhmmss) suggests using `DateTime.TimeOfDay` instead, for the same result.