# How could i convert TimeZone string to TimeSpan and vice versa?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have string such as following :

> "+10:30" , "+04:50" , "-10:20"

which are in timezone format. How could i convert it to TimeSpan and vice versa ?

---

I have already tried to use TimeSpan.Pars(..) but no luck, keep getting exceptions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TimeSpan.Parse time format hhmmss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833830/timespan-parse-time-format-hhmmss)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the possible duplicate referenced.  It seems a different question to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
TimeSpan.Parse(yourTimeZoneString.TrimStart('+'));
```

It's the '+' that `TimeSpan.Parse()` doesn't understand.  If you just trim the leading '+' from the string, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the + signs before parsing. This works for me:

```
var l = new List<string>(){"+10:30" , "+04:50" , "-10:20"};
foreach(var ts in l) {
    Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.Parse(ts.Replace("+","")).ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimeSpan.Parse method, it will accept string values from your example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx The only issue is that I am not sure will it accept "+" sign, however, it is very easy to remove it with String.Replace.

Comment: I think you mean `TimeSpan.Parse()`