# Why does TimeSpan.ParseExact not work

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan

This is a bit wierd. Parsing a text field with a valid timespan fails if I try to be precise!

```
const string tmp = "17:23:24";
//works
var t1 = TimeSpan.Parse(tmp);
//fails
var t2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(tmp, "hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The second parse fails with an exception "Input string was not in a correct format." from DateTime.

Comment: Maybe you need `HH` instead of `hh` (24 hr format)

Comment: @V4Vendetta: you should post that as an answer; it's likely correct.

Comment: @JohnTotetWoo: Which date? There's no date in a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments/answers - no HH is NOT a TimeSpan format string, that's not the answer. It's Jon's reply: TimeSpan.ParseExact does not handle separators, which is why it's failing. But Parse does - go figure! You have to escape the : values

Answer (score 106, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx#Other):

> Any other unescaped character in a format string, including a
>   white-space character, is interpreted as a custom format specifier. In
>   most cases, the presence of any other unescaped character results in a
>   FormatException.
>
> There are two ways to include a literal character in a format string:
>
> - Enclose it in single quotation marks (the literal string delimiter).
> - Precede it with a backslash ("\"), which is interpreted as an escape character. This means that, in C#, the format string must
>     either be @-quoted, or the literal character must be preceded by an
>     additional backslash.
>
> The .NET Framework does not define a grammar for separators in time
>   intervals. This means that the separators between days and hours,
>   hours and minutes, minutes and seconds, and seconds and fractions of a
>   second must all be treated as character literals in a format string.

So, the solution is to specify the format string as

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(tmp, "hh\\:mm\\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Nice answer, Jon - I'd never realised that `ParseExact` ignores the 12/24 hour convention with the formatters.

Comment: So it is - learned something new today! Odd that Parse handles separators but ParseExact doesn't!

Comment: I was hoping this would solve my problem related to converting from `string` to `TimeSpan` in the Expression string of `DataTable.Select()`.  However, no luck. Filed a bug [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806804/datatable-select-unable-to-convert-string-to-timespan-net-framework-4).

Comment: you could also use `@"hh\:mm\:ss"`.

Comment: I have a question about this answer: Why does 
**TimeSpan.ParseExact(tmp, "HH:mm:ss.ffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)**
work perfectly without any separators?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
var t2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(tmp, "c", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Source: 
[Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I hadn't noticed the 'c' format, which takes care of the separator issue: another new thing learned!

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to deal with the difference in format specifiers between `TimeSpan.ParseExact` and `DateTime.ParseExact` you can just parse your string as a `DateTime` and get the `TimeOfDay` component as a `TimeSpan` like this:

```
var t2 = DateTime.ParseExact(tmp, "hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2552455/696391) for how to go the other way: formatting a TimeSpan using DateTime format specifiers.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that HH is not really for `TimeSpan`

> The custom TimeSpan format specifiers do not include placeholder
>   separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours,
>   hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these
>   symbols must be included in the custom format string as string
>   literals. For example, "dd.hh\:mm" defines a period (.) as the
>   separator between days and hours, and a colon (:) as the separator
>   between hours and minutes.

Hence the correct way would be as Jon mentioned to escape using **"\"** [Read More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx#Other)

<strike>Your `TimeSpan` is **"17:23:24"** which is in the 24 hour format and it should be parsed using `HH` format and not `hh` which is for 12 hour formats.</strike>

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(tmp, "HH:mm:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Check out [the formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Not relevant: the specifier for hours that are not counted as part of days is `hh`.

Comment: You are linking to the `DateTime` format strings, which are different than the [`TimeSpan` format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287).

Comment: Nope, not correct. Timespan does not support HH, it only supports hh

Comment: @Jon Indeed that's the case, real eye opener for me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use this
It works
use

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, “h\\:mm”, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     var t2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(tmp, "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - see Jon's answer for the actual problem.