# string to TimeSpan via pattern

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time

I have this time string `18:08:23.580` the pattern seems to be `HH:mm:ss.fff`
How I can convert this string using my pattern to `TimeSpan` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simpy use [`TimeSpan.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) without an explicit pattern:

```
TimeSpan.Parse("18:08:23.580")
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/XA7uKu)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact("18:08:23.580", "HH:mm:ss.fff", ultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var span = t.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Parse(String, IFormatProvider)**

> Converts the string representation of a time interval to its TimeSpan equivalent.

More information: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the way to go:

```
 TimeSpan ts =  TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, @"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See also:
[Why does TimeSpan.ParseExact not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719055/why-does-timespan-parseexact-not-work)

And: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx