# FormatException mm:ss

Tags: c#, timespan, formatexception

I want to extract the TotalSeconds from a String with format "MM:SS". For instance: 01:20 I spect 80 (seconds)

I do it and I get an Exception:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(time.ToString(), "mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).TotalSeconds;
```

What do I do wrong??

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I found the solution in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719055/why-does-timespan-parseexact-not-work)
Format: "mm\\:ss"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(time.ToString(), "mm\\:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).TotalSeconds;
```

Read more about Costum TimeSpan Formatting on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx#Other)

Backslash is as an escape character. This means that, in C#, the format string must either be @-quoted, or mm:ss must be separated by backslash.

Comment: @Ziggy if it was helpful, please mark it as an answer so others can see what was the solution for this issue. Is there anything else we can help you with?

Answer (score 2):

If `time` is a `DateTime`, you can simply do something like

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(time.Ticks);
Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalSeconds);
```

If you want it to work as per your code, then, note the output from `ToString()` method does not match the string pattern you have provided.  Format it to so that the output matches the required pattern, eg,

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(time.ToString("mm:ss"), "mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to TimeSpan custom format guide here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

You have to sort-of-escape the colon with a backslach, so your format should look like this

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(time.ToString(), @"mm\:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).TotalSeconds;
```