# am_late set to 8:01:00 but when its 10:00 am it says on time

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Private Sub BtnAMin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnAMin.Click
    Dim amlate As String = "8:01:00 AM"
    Dim remarks As String
    Dim d1 As Date = "8:00:00 AM"
    Dim d2 As Date = LblTime.Text
    Dim am_late As Long
    If LblTime.Text >= amlate Then
        remarks = "LATE"
        am_late = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, d1, d2)
        MsgBox("LATE BY:" & am_late & "....MINUTES")
    Else
        remarks = "ON TIME"
    End If

    Try
        With com
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO attendance (id_no, am_in, am_remarks, am_late, date) VALUES (@id_no,@am_in,@am_remarks,@am_late,@date)"
        End With
        com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@id_no", Txtid.Text))
        com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@am_in", LblTime.Text))
        com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@am_remarks", remarks))
        com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@am_late", am_late))
        com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@date", LblDate.Text))
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If remarks = "LATE" Then
            MessageBox.Show("You Are Late!")
        ElseIf remarks = "ON TIME" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Very good you come on time!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    BtnAMin.Enabled = False
    BtnAMout.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

when i timein AM 8:01:00 -09:59:00 something like that it will promt you are late
and its minutes
but when i timein AM 10:00 Am onward its on time

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a `DateTimePicker` control?

Comment: @rowland we only used timer for the date

Comment: you are comparing time as string here, hence `AM 1XXXX` always considered smaller than `AM 8XXXX` whatever `XXXX..` part is. Try to parse times string to `TimeSpan` then compare them [[For Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833830/timespan-parse-time-format-hhmmss)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you already have Date version of the time string in `d1` and `d2`. So simply compare the `Date` version instead of the `String` version of time :

```
If d2 >= d1 Then
    remarks = "LATE"
    am_late = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, d1, d2)
    MsgBox("LATE BY:" & am_late & "....MINUTES")
Else
    remarks = "ON TIME"
End If
```